# How to animate resize smaller logo image on scroll?

Tags: jquery-animate, onscroll

I was able to figure out how to animate header resize on scroll. However, I can't seem to figure out how to also animate a header logo image to make it smaller on scroll. Any help to modify the code below would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    if
    ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("header").addClass("shrink");
    } else {
        $("header").removeClass("shrink");
    }
});
```

```css
#logo {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    /* animation magic */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.shrink {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div id="logo">
            <header><img src="https://www.computerhope.com/cdn/computer-hope.jpg"></header>
        </div>
        
        <div id="content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would first of all change a bit your HTML like so:

```
 <header>
     <div id="logo">
         <img src="https://www.computerhope.com/cdn/computer-hope.jpg">
     </div>
 </header>
```

And change you css to this:

```
#logo 
{
   width:200px;/*give it a fixed size*/
   margin:0 auto;
   /* animation magic */
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out ;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out ;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out ;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out ;
}

#logo img 
{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}

header 
{
   width: 100%;
   padding: 30px 0;
   background: #000;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
   z-index: 9999;
}

.shrink 
{
   width:100px;/*change the size here*/
}
```

Change your jQuery to this:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 100)
    {
       $("#logo").addClass("shrink");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#logo").removeClass("shrink");
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, I added this and it animates smoothly on scroll down, but does not animate smoothly back to to original size on scroll up:

Comment: .shrink img {
 max-width: 150px;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

Comment: What did you add?

Comment: This CSS: 
.shrink img { max-width: 150px; -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; transition: all .3s ease-in-out; }

Comment: Notice when you scroll back up and the header height grows, the logo abuptly (without animation) grows larger.  I want to figure out why it is not animating the logo size on scroll up.

Comment: You are setting the with to the img but not to the container. The image is responsive so you need to resize the container and the image will resize accordingly.